# Basement shower drain need replacement?

Tags: plumbing

Just curious, was looking at the current state of our shower drain pipe and noticed it looks terrible (corroded).

Is this any need of concern? We were thinking about renovating in a few years or so.

If it should be replaced, would this be a large job?

[image: Drain]
[image: Drain Pipe]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty much what old galvanized pipes look like. I wouldn't do anything unless you have a leak. It's more likely that you'll experience a clog, though, from accumulated corrosion and deposits inside the pipe. Rarely do pipes rust all the way through.

I would plan on replacing as much metal drain pipe as possible when/if you do renovate, though. In my home I cut channels in the slab and replaced most of my galvanized and cast iron with PVC after it started backing up from the kitchen. One two-inch line was down to a finger-sized trickle due to rock hard deposits in the pipe under the floor.

Comment: Perfect, me being a new home owner I think I'm overly cautious (which is not a bad thing I suppose). Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Me, I'd want to brush off all that debris. Would that be a bad idea, perhaps speeding up corrosion?

Comment: I had the same thought. Technically it'll encourage more corrosion, but probably not to a degree that it's a problem.

Comment: @Shinobii, Price inquiries are off-topic on this site and inappropriate as comments on old questions. Please see the [Help pages](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help) to better understand how SE works. If you have a new question about your project, please post it in a new question.